# How know SSL fingerprint for some website using Linux CLI?

Tags: linux, ssl, openssl, command-line-interface, esp8266

I'm trying update (using esp8266 microcontroller), update a DNS record hosted on DigitalOcean, using the API.

How do I do to get HTTPS fingerprint using Linux CLI, for use on my code?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using ESP (arduino IDE) library **WiFiClientSecure.h,** you need declare the "const" variable for fingerprint, like bellow:

```
const char* fingerprint = "9A 8E 2F 33 95 CA 72 4F 47 26 54 52 A4 E5 00 70 F0 BD ED 85";
```

So anyhow, these values can be obtained running the command

```
$ echo | openssl s_client -connect host.example.com:443 |& openssl x509 -fingerprint -noout
```

Result:

```
SHA1 Fingerprint=9A:8E:2F:33:95:CA:72:4F:47:26:54:52:A4:E5:00:70:F0:BD:ED:85
```